# Is there Windows based mining software that allows you to set precentage of GPU/CPU or set low priority

Tags: miner-configuration, mining-software

Essentially the title is my question.

I have 3 Windows boxes that already run 24/7 for specific low CPU usage tasks.
Was hoping I could find mining software I could run on them that will not affect their functionality.

If not I might be able to "schedule" mining for off peak times?

Sorry if these are dumb questions but very new to all this.

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin CPU and GPU mining is not general considered to be worthwhile anymore because of high difficulty.

If you wish to proceed, you could try [limiting the mining application to a single core in task manager](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/change-the-processor-affinity-setting-in-windows-7-to-gain-a-performance-edge/) for CPU mining.  Additionally Some miners have "aggression" or equivalent settings that may be able to limit the resources the process takes.